# Align buttons inside a TableRow

Tags: android, tablelayout

I'm developing an Android application.

I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="200px"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="5px"
        android:text="aaaaa"/>
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="5px"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="dddddd"/>
  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonsTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button
                android:text="@string/yes"
                android:id="@+id/playGame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                android:text="@string/no"
                android:id="@+id/noPlayGame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to put playGame button in the left side of the center, and noPlayGame button in the right side of the center.

Now, both appear aligned to the left of the TableRow.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: I've added the complete layout and the modifications suggested by **Ashay**.
**2nd EDIT**:
 **THE SOLUTION**
I've added to `TableLayout` the following: `android:stretchColumns="0,1"`. Now the buttons are center aligned but they fill their entiry column!!!

Comment: Probably worth posting your own answer and marking it as answered, so that this doesn't keep showing up in the unanswered questions list.

Comment: I don't like to answer my owns questions.

Comment: That's it.Thank you.Your solution work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/stringtxt1"></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stringtxt2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"></Button>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 10):

I posted my code, I hope that will help others users to resolve theirs problems (center content). I wanted to center two buttons in table row, here is my code, which solve this problem:

we indicate which columns will be stretched in prop android:strechColumns="a,b.." using comma-delimited list

```
      <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttonGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1" > 

        <TableRow>
            <Button
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button1Name" 
                android:layout_gravity="right"/>

            <Button
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button2Name" 
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

I hope that it will help. Sorry for my english :/

Answer (score 10):

For centering a single button on a single row:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/rowNameHere"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnDoStuff"
            android:text="Do Stuff" />
</TableRow>
```

After reviewing the above answers, I grabbed a few things from each answer and this worked for me.

Comment: Thank you!! `android:gravity="end"` works for me to align button to the right of table row.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm shocked that this answer is still relevant after so many years.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line `<TableRow android:layout_gravity="center">`
And give `android:fill_containt` in table row for both **height** & **width**

**EDITED ANSWER**:
 Well, I'm so sorry for the last posts spelling mistake

Through XML it seems impossible for `TableLayout`. You need to set this UI in code in oncreate. 
In your java file you can set those by using below.

```
playGame.setWidth(ScreenWidth()/2-var);
noPlayGame.setWidth(ScreenWidth()/2-var);
```

here `var` can be used to set the distance between these 2 buttons like 10 or 30.
 Also, your xml will get change as follows:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonsTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:text="yes"
                android:id="@+id/playGame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <Button
                android:text="no"
                android:id="@+id/noPlayGame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The method `ScreenWidth()` can be used for getting width of the screen through these methods

```
private int ScreenWidth() {
        DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        String width=""+dm.widthPixels;
        return Integer.parseInt(width);
}
```

Comment: android:fill_containt? I haven't found this "property" on android's documentation.

Comment: I have edit the question adding in more details. Your answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I added two dummy textviews to align my button in the center.

```
<TableRow>
    <TextView 
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight=".25" 
        android:layout_width="0dip"         
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignIn" 
        android:text="Log In"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50" 
        android:layout_width="0dip" 
        />
    <TextView 
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight=".25" 
        android:layout_width="0dip"         
    />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: is this the only solution? I don't think this is the correct one.... adding empty textviews to center a button?